Load kernel 1 failed in NBMiner
Im trying to use NBMiner_Win but i get next error
[21:21:46] ERROR - Load kernel 1 failed.
[21:21:39] INFO -  |ID|PCI|  CC| Memory| CU| RamType| RamVendor|
[21:21:46] ERROR - Error loading kernel for AMD Radeon RX 7900 XTX[1100].
[21:21:39] INFO - *| 0|  3|1100| 24560M| 96|        |          | AMD Radeon RX 7900 XTX
[21:21:41] INFO - ethash - Logging in to ethash.unmineable.com(138.68.130.227):4444 ...
[21:21:41] INFO - ethash - Login succeeded.
[21:21:41] INFO - API:  0.0.0.0:22333
[21:21:41] INFO - API server started.
[21:21:43] INFO - Device 0 started, Free mem = 24560 MB.
[21:21:46] INFO - ethash - New job: ethash.unmineable.com:4444, ID: 7b99b8fd, HEIGHT: 20005955, DIFF: 8.590G
[21:21:46] WARN - QMutex: destroying locked mutex

anyone any idea? I tried to update the AMD software
Thanks
